# Load a numpy array into C from a file that was saved with numpy.save(...)

Tags: c++, python, c, numpy

I'd like to access data in a C program that resides in a file that was written from python using numpy.save(...). So far, I was looking for a way to call the C version of numpy.load my C program, but it seems there is no directly accessible C version, because numpy.load uses the pickle module. Another solution would be to start an embedded python interpreter from C and call numpy.load in that interpreter, which should return the numpy array, which I can then access in the usual manner. However the last appraoch seems a bit to heavy, because I have to use the interpreter. Is there a better way to directly load the numpy array into C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.npy` format is not really meant to be read from outside NumPy.  There are many formats available with provide both, excellent C and Python libraries, like HDF5 and NetCDF, so I can't see any reason whatsoever to access native NumPy files from C.

If you want to do this anyway, here are [the docs of the `.npy` format](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/pydoc/numpy.lib.format.html).  It does not use pickle internally unless you stored Python objects in your array (but in that case, I would wonder what you are going to do with those in your C program).