# How to read and write npy format in C++?

Tags: python, c++

I want to store and read `.npy` ( Numpy Array Format) using `C++`. I found a [Github repository](https://github.com/rogersce/cnpy) which does it, but it's quite old, and I want to implement it in `C++11`.

Can anyone give me a hint or a way to start this mini-project?

As this question was put on hold for being broad, I am narrowing it down, and moving forward to ask, how to design the C++ I/O methods for the `.npy`, [file format](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html)?

Comment: The library you found is quite small, I would expect that it would be pretty easy to just fork it and modernize it as you see fit. That being said, maybe it hasn't been updated in a while simply because it works?

Comment: I want to port the `.npy` I/O feature of this C++ module  to another project, that being in `C++11`. So I need to start fresh.

Comment: C++11 can typically compile code written for C++03 just fine. Have you tried this library?

Comment: Yes, but the repo uses some old and scary things like `typeid`. And, I need to also write some wrappers using the final port. So, I thought it would be better to write my own library. I needed some help in the memory management and, how `.npy` is parsed. [Check this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html) for the format specification.

Comment: I dunno what to tell you, this code is small and not terribly complex, if you really insist on it being modernized, I say go for it. I don't think that there is much interest here on SO of doing that part for you though.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Comment: @MonaJalal Check this repo https://github.com/rogersce/cnpy

Comment: If you are especially interested in reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314432/load-a-numpy-array-into-c-from-a-file-that-was-saved-with-numpy-save