# How to get the ndarrays and its dimension from the binary file?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, binaryfiles, numpy-ndarray

I have a binary file that contains the `ndarray` of shape `(2,3,4)` which I created using the following python script.

```
import numpy as np
#initialize an array
arr1 = np.array([[[ 0, 1,  2],
              [ 3, 4,  5],
              [ 6,  7,  8],
              [ 9, 10, 11]],

             [[12, 13, 14],
              [15, 16, 17],
              [18, 19, 20],
              [21, 22, 23]]])


# open a binary file in write mode
arr.astype('int16').tofile("arr.bin")
```

Well, I wanted to open the binary file in a C++ program to get all the values of the `ndarray`in same order. I have tried the following.

```
int *arr_out;
arr_out = (int16_t*)malloc((width * height * channels * sizeof(int16_t)));
//where width is 4, height is 3 and channels 2.

//arr.bin is the name of the binary file
fp = fopen("arr.bin","rb");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error with File Opening \n");
    exit(1);
}

fread(arr_out, sizeof(int16_t), width * height * channels, fp);
```

Well, I was about to find the values of the multidimensional array and the first dimension of the array using `sizeof(arr_out[0])`, how to find the rest of the dimensions so that I can pass the multidimensional array to a function. Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There's a header at the start with the `dtype` and dimensions... https://stackoverflow.com/a/5314578/2836621

Comment: Thanks  @MarkSetchell its useful. I have modified my code and now able to get the desired values as expected.